# Borde botón un solo color

Tags: css

Buenas,

¿como puedo hacer para que el borde salga solo de un color?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad **CSS** `border`:

Añade lo siguiente al estilo de tu botón (ejemplo):

```
border: 2px solid red;
```

En la propiedad `border` defines los siguientes parámetros:

> border: [grosor del borde] [estilo del borde] [color del borde];

Aquí te dejo un poco más de [información acerca de esta propiedad CSS](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border/).